# Foundation: how to change h2 font-size?

Tags: css, wordpress, zurb-foundation, font-size, html-heading

On our WordPress blog, it seems the style is inherited from the `foundation.css` file.

In particular, the font-size of headings, that we would like to change.

For instance, [on this page](http://www.timyo.com/blog/yin-yang-email/), when we inspect element, it seems that the font-size of `h2` is defined in `foundation.css`, on `line 2813`.

So, we changed the size of `h2` in the foundation.css file, on this very particular line, but we still get the same result.

It seems like something it overriding our changes.

What is the right way to change headings font-size?

Comment: Try to add !important; if it works, its because another css override it ex. font-size: 30px !important;

Comment: This seems to have fixed our problem. Do you want to add it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the size and it doesn't work into your css,

You can Add the `!important;` parameters at the end of the line. Ex.:

```
h2 { font-size: 30px !important; }
```

please, [read this](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/) if you want to know how to use it. Don't abuse of !important if not necessary!!

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to flush the cache when you refresh the page to see your changes to foundation.css. It's possible that your browser is caching the previous version of foundation.css and your changes are being ignored while it renders (but external users may be seeing them).

Try shift-cmd-R in Chrome, or have the JS console open, and a pulldown menu will appear on the refresh button (in Chrome).

Comment: Thanks for this trick (and the shortcut). It may not be the cause of the problem though, since we worked on separate devices and in developer mode.